# Dictionary out of list in python

Tags: python

How can I create a dictionary out of the a in python?

If I have a list like this:

```
a = ["Albert Einstein", "Nils Bohr"]
```

And I want it to become this:

```
b = {'Albert Eienstein': ['Albert', 'Eienstein'], 'Neils Bohr': ['Neils', 'Bohr']}
```

Comment: Can't understand what the character `b` and `=` is doing there. Moreover, what you want as output seems not a list, but a string.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? Your last line could use a bit of an explanation

Comment: Also, that's not how you spell 'Einstein

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lista = ["Albert Eienstein","Neils Bohr"]
dictb = {}
for elem in lista:
    dictb[elem] = elem.split(' ')

print dictb

Output: {'Neils Bohr': ['Neils', 'Bohr'], 'Albert Eienstein': ['Albert', 'Eienstein']}
```

Comment: You got what I wanted to say!!Thanks

Comment: Then @user997704 wanted a dict of lists... (you should probably edit the title).

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand your question. Are you saying that you want this?

```
list_of_lists = [['Albert', 'Einstein'], ['Neils', 'Bohr']]
```

Or this?

```
dict_of_lists = {'Albert Einstein':['Albert', 'Einstein'], 
                 'Neils Bohr':['Neils', 'Bohr']}
```

Or are you saying you want to convert from one to the other?

```
>>> l = ["Albert Eienstein", "Neils Bohr"]
>>> d = dict((i, i.split()) for i in l)
>>> d
{'Neils Bohr': ['Neils', 'Bohr'], 'Albert Eienstein': ['Albert', 'Eienstein']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the list inside the other, ie

```
scientists = [["Albert","Einstein"],["Neils","Bohr"]]
```